# how to fix "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ in JSON at position . . . "

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json, ajax

i am trying to output a `json_encode` on a php code. and then I suddenly caught this error on the network tab in google chrome. this is my first time handling errors in ajax and json.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at String.<anonymous> (script.js:61)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (script.js:60)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ script.js:61
each @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ script.js:60
u @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ script.js:52
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
```

clicking the script.js:61 points me at the part of code (pointed by my comment in the jquery code)

```
$("[id^='deleteNotes']").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/deleteidentifier.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                id_delete: id
            }
        })
        .done(function(result_query_sql_deletedStatus_notes){
            $.each(JSON.parse(result_query_sql_deletedStatus_notes), function(key, value) {
                if (JSON.parse(value).deleted_status == "n") { //the cursor points me here. precisely, at the end of JSON and start of .parse
                    alert("Moved to deleted folder.");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    alert("Note permanently deleted!");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

i want to use the value of deleted_status on the json_encode value as a trigger of the json alert. here's the json encode.

```
{
"note_record":"1_5cdb7ad317291.jpeg",
"note_type":"images",
"note_title":"",
"user_id":"9",
"date_created":"Wednesday, May 15, 2019. | 10:34:59 AM",
"date_updated":"",
"note_id":"1",
"archived_status":"n",
"deleted_status":"y",
"date_deleted":"Sunday, May 19, 2019. | 07:59:32 PM",
"image_directory":"image_uploads\/1_5cdb7ad317291.jpeg"
}
```

I honestly cannot point out the error here because there's no understandable error message for me to look at in my level of knowledge.

EDIT: Here's the `deleteidentifier.php` which is called in ajax

```
<?php
    include_once("../db.php");
    include "../session.php";
    if (isset($_POST["id_delete"])) {
        $sql_deletedStatus_notes = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_id = '". $_POST['id_delete'] ."'";
        $query_sql_deletedStatus_notes = $conn->query($sql_deletedStatus_notes);
        $result_query_sql_deletedStatus_notes = $query_sql_deletedStatus_notes->fetch_assoc();

        if ($result_query_sql_deletedStatus_notes["deleted_status"] == "y") {
            if ($result_query_sql_deletedStatus_notes["note_type"] == "notes") {
                $sql_delete_notes = "DELETE FROM notes WHERE note_id = '" . $_POST['id_delete'] . "'";
                $query_sql_delete_notes = $conn->query($sql_delete_notes);
            }
            else {
                $sql_delete_images = "DELETE FROM notes WHERE image_directory LIKE 'image_uploads/" . $_POST['id_delete'] . "' !_% ESCAPE '!'";
                $query_sql_delete_images = $conn->query($sql_delete_images);
            }
        }
        else {
            $sql_update_deletedStatus_notes = "UPDATE notes SET deleted_status='y', date_deleted = '" . $date_time_curr . "' WHERE note_id = '". $_POST['id_delete'] ."' OR image_directory LIKE 'image_uploads/" . $_POST['id_delete'] . "!_%' ESCAPE '!'";
            $query_sql_update_deletedStatus_notes = $conn->query($sql_update_deletedStatus_notes);
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
    echo json_encode($result_query_sql_deletedStatus_notes);
?>
```

Comment: Can you please add the full JSON / value to your question? Depending on the content type of your PHP, the JSON might be parsed automatically. Maybe there is an additional underscore printed by your PHP script as well. Without knowing the full result from your AJAX call, it's hard to help here.

Comment: i've included the PHP script now. the JSON above is the full values of JSON encode.

Comment: That's actually not what I wanted to see - when you have a look into the Network Tab of Chrome again when the Ajax is executed, you can see the server response. Maybe the result is a) no valid JSON or b) automatically parsed by Javascript

Comment: in what part of the network tab should I see the response you need to see?

Comment: When you have the network tab open during the Ajax Request, you'll see a new line with `deleteidentifier.php`. Click it, then look at Response

Comment: it's the same as the ones before I edit this post, but yea, i've copy paste the response now.

Comment: Ok, then I see your problem here I guess. I will post it as an answer to provide a readable code example

Comment: thank you, kind stranger :)

Comment: No problem - let me know if it works ;)

Comment: yes, it works :) thank you stranger :D

but a new problem shows up. not on the json response, but on the deleteidentifier.php code itself.

Comment: Well, you can then create a new question for this if required.
If the answer is sufficient for the JSON parsing problem, please mark it as the solution.

Comment: turns out, it's just a missing single quotation. thanks Kryptur for all your professional help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You parse the received JSON twice. With your `$.each` call you then iterate over the object and try to parse the value of each object key. In the first iteration, with your example data, you try to parse "1_5cdb7ad317291.jpeg" as JSON, which is no valid JSON. Thus, you can access the value after the first parse.

```
$("[id^='deleteNotes']").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/deleteidentifier.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                id_delete: id
            }
        })
        .done(function(result_query_sql_deletedStatus_notes){
            var data = JSON.parse(result_query_sql_deletedStatus_notes);
            if (data.deleted_status == "n") { //the cursor points me here. precisely, at the end of JSON and start of .parse
                alert("Moved to deleted folder.");
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                alert("Note permanently deleted!");
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
```